# Issue with canonical url, when using mysql

Tags: python, django, web

Currently I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04`, I'm trying to develop blogging websites using django. I'm trying to use canonical url for displaying more meaningful url format.

Everything is fine when I'm using django default database (i.e `sqlite3`). But when I switch from `sqlite3` to `mysql` I get this issue :

My post_detail page is not displaying.

For better explanation of my problem screenshot is given below, what i'm facing.
    For better explanation of my problem screenshot is given below, what i'm facing.

[image]

But I'm not facing any types of error while using sqlite3..
So, Please help me out from this problem

Comment: I don't know you think a "canonical URL" has anything to do with this. The error is telling you that your MySQL database does not contain a Post for that slug. Did you create one?

Comment: Yeah, this same example is working when I'm using sqlite3, but after switching from sqlite3 to mysql, this error occurs.

Comment: Fine but did you create the Post in your new MySQL database?

Comment: Thanks for you help, finally I solve this error, This error is related to  USE_TZ = True, Making this false solve my problem